# wrap text in floated situation (css)

Tags: html, css

I have the following code

HTML:

```
<div>
   <h3> Lorem ...</h3>
   <a>some link</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
a {
    float: left;
}

h3 {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

If there is enough horizontal space both elements sit nicely next to each other, but if not enough space, the anchor is pushed down (not what I want) I would like to see the **h3** element's text wrap instead. Furthermore, the text inside the elements can be anything, meaning that their width is variable. Any suggestions ?

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ygnbgL7k/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`float` doesn’t work this way on elements higher up in the DOM tree. (The only reason that the link did not get pushed down under the text content of the `h3` to begin with was that you did display the latter as `inline-block`.)

If you can place your link before the `h3`, then it’s easy (you just have to remove `inline-block` form the `h3` as well) – http://jsfiddle.net/ygnbgL7k/9/

EDIT:

> [ from comment]: but the only problem with that solution is that the wrapped text starts at the beginning of the next line (under the floated anchor).

If you don’t want that, add

```
h3 { overflow:hidden; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ygnbgL7k/15/

Comment: That indeed works, but the only problem with that solution is that the wrapped text starts at the beginning of the next line (under the floated anchor). But thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: Could you explain why `overflow:hidden` has this effect on the element ?

Comment: Because it establishes a new _block formatting context_.

Answer (score 2):

either

```
h3{
     white-space: nowrap;
     overflow: hidden;
     text-overflow: hidden;
}
```

or give them widths

```
h3{
      width:50%;
}

a{
     width:50%;
}
```

or whichever values u want so that they won't get out of their boundries

Answer (score 1):

I don't exactly understand how you want the output to be, i've given two outputs below.

1) **`<h3>` and `<a>` tag side by side without width**:

You can use `display:table` property which requires no width

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Kritika/ygnbgL7k/6/)**

CSS:

```
div
{
  display:table;
}

a {

    display:table-cell;
}

h3 {
    display: table-cell;

}
```

2) **`<a>` tag continuing with the text in the `<h3>` tag:**

You can use `display:inline`

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Kritika/ygnbgL7k/16/)**

CSS:

```
a {
    display:inline;
}

h3{
   display:inline;  
}
```

Comment: this does exactly what I need

Comment: @JeanlucaScaljeri: kindly accept the answer, so that it does not add to the unanswered list.

Comment: I have, but the answer below now also does what I need, and without the `display: table`. Thanks!

Comment: @JeanlucaScaljeri: Good :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
h3{
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```